# Has anyone done cluster analysis on the data dumps?

Tags: discussion, data-dump

I'm curious if people have found tags that are related to other tags that might not always appear together. I suppose if you wanted to take this a step further, you might also analyze questions to group related questions into families based on full-text analysis + tags.

Anyone working on anything like this?

Comment: Well, it looks like I know what I'll be doing at some point. If no one else is already doing this, I would open-source this and let anyone who wants to contribute to do so.

Comment: Go for it; sounds interesting! :)

Comment: And, any results? I remember some presented cluster analyses on the data science blog of Stackoverflow around 2018-19 by Julia Silge I think, but cannot find it right now.

Comment: Perhaps readers will enjoy a link to querying the [related tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/397377).